# NPM: Should peer dependencies be listed as a dependency on the host package?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

The following scenario:
I have my host package called "MyAwesomeApplication" and a component library package called "MyAwesomeComponentLibrary".

Inside MyAwesomeComponentLibrary I make use of an external npm package called "AnAwesomeComponent":

```
// MyAwesomeComponentLibrary
import AnAwesomeComponent from "an-awesome-component";
...
export default MyAwesomeComponentWrapper;
______________________________________

// MyAwesomeApplication
import MyAwesomeComponentWrapper from "my-awesome-component-library"
```

Now because in MyAwesomeApplication I never directly import the external "an-awesome-component" package. This means it's not a direct dependency for my application.

Since NPM 7 peerDependencies are installed automatically, I don't see a reason for adding the external package as a dependency as well.

My question dumbs down to this:
Which structure is preferred?

```
// package.json - MyAwesomeApplication
dependencies
 - MyAwesomeComponentLibrary
 - AnAwesomeComponent // THIS IS THE DIFFERENCE

// package.json - MyAwesomeComponentLibrary
peerDependencies
 - AnAwesomeComponent
```

vs

```
// package.json - MyAwesomeApplication
dependencies
 - MyAwesomeComponentLibrary

// package.json - MyAwesomeComponentLibrary
peerDependencies
 - AnAwesomeComponent
```

All the resources I found on this topic don't specifically recommend anything in that scenario.
I appreciate all answers :D

Comment: I'm fast approaching a story where this will be very relevant.  I was planning to experiment with your second approach, and if it works, go with that.  Were you able to find any explicit recommendation, or experiment with it yourself?

Comment: @MetaSean We went with the second approach. Practically it really makes no difference since NPM 7 as long as the version numbers are the same. We only add a peerdependency as a dependency as soon as it is directly imported on the host package.
I think this way the least amount of maintenance is needed

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping would happen.  Thank you so much for confirming!